# I want to use one int in two scripts and decrease it in the second one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, int, collider

I want to use this int in the two scripts: `public int wood;`
I want the value of the int to be the same in both scripts.

This is my first script:

```
public class Tree : 
  
MonoBehaviour { public int wood;
    
     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
     {
         wood += 1;
     }
    }
```

This is my second script which I want the wood to use in it:

```
public class Base : MonoBehaviour {

 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
 {
 }
}
```

I want to decrease the wood value in `OnTriggerEnter2D`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the button component to your gameobject.(To get this component in code use `Button btn = Gameobject.GetComponent<Button>();`. To detect a click on the button you can use the [`onclick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) event the button has.

```cs
void Start(){
    btn.onClick.AddListener(ButtonClicked);
}
void ButtonClicked(){
    //code
}
```

You can also add the [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) and [`OnMouseUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html) functions to create a button(this would only require the collider component, and not the button component.

```
void OnMouseDown(){
    clicking = true;
}
void OnMouseUp(){
    clicking = false;
}
```

Comment: I wrote Debug.Log("HI") in the start void but it didnt say any hing in console

it didnt work I wrote:
{
    bool clicking=false;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        clicking = true;
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        if (clicking == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("clicking");
        }

}

Comment: Did you have a collider attached to the gameobject? Both methods I said should be done individually.  However, you also mentioned void Start did not work, is the script attached to a gameobject(that is in the scene).

Comment: I added

public new GameObject gameObject;
but it didnt say any thing in cosole the other codes are the same

Comment: I used the other solution
Button button;

   public new GameObject gameObject;
   

    
    void Update()
    {
        button.onClick.AddListener(onclick);
    }


    void onclick()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
but the object didnt got destroyer

Comment: First. You are creating a new gameobject called "gameObject". Usally gameObject would refer to the object the script is set to, however you have reset it with a new gameObject.  Try using this.gameObject to destroy the button. Second, put the `button.onClick.AddListener(onclick);` in `void Start()`, or the button will keep adding a listener from the button  to the void. Finally, try putting a debug.log in the onclick function to see if it is running.

Answer (score 0):

When a button is clicked it throws an event.
So you need to register what you want to do when this event fires.

There are multiple ways, but one could be like:

```
buttonVariable.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonDoSomething);
```

Using [lambda expresion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) will be:

```
button.onClick.AddListener(() => OnButtonDoSomething());
```

So you need to declare this on `Start`, `OnEnable` or `Awake` method in any of your scripts. And then have a `Button` reference so you can store your `buttonVariable`and finally declare your method `OnButtonDoSomething`.

To fit your question, you'll store a boolean variable called `buttonGotClicked` and in your new created method, set this boolean like:

```
private void OnButtonDoSomething()
{
    buttonGotClicked = true;
}
```

Then you can do `if(buttonGotClicked)...`